# Possible to have TypeScript class optional properties fall back to default value if omitted?

Tags: typescript, default

Is there any way to assign the class member properties default values if they are omitted by the user?

I have a custom class that constains an optional instance of another class:

```
export class MyClass1 {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "";
        this.classInstance = new MyClass2();
    }
    name: string;           // name of the object
    classInstance?: MyClass2;
}

class MyClass2 {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "MyClass2 initial name";
    }

    name: string;
}
```

The content for *MyClass1* comes from JSON, so some sometimes the member variable *classInstance* can be undefined. In these cases I'd like the *MyClass1* constructor to initiate *new MyClass2()* into *classInstance* member variable.

This is how I assign create the instance of MyClass1:

```
let myNewClass: MyClass1 = {
    name: "MyClass"
}
```

Because the *classInstance* is omitted, I assumed it would have the default value set in the constructor. However, this is not the case. I also tried removing the optional sign from the *classInstance*-variable, but this gives a compilation error because then the object has to match the structure of *MyClass1*. I guess I managed to compile without errors by casting, but it didn't solve the problem (although I'm not sure if this compiled properly either):

```
let myNewClass: MyClass1 = {
    name: "MyClass"
} as MyClass1
```

In neither case did *classInstance* get the default value that the constructor sets, it came out null/undefined.

For me it doesn't matter how the casting problem is solved (whether to set properties optional or use casting), as long as I have control over the default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is

```
let myNewClass: MyClass1 = {
    name: "MyClass"
} as MyClass1
```

here is *not* `MyClass1` instance. TypeScript type system was 'cheated' to think that plain object is `MyClass1` instance.

It will be transpiled to `var myNewClass = { name: "MyClass" }`. `MyClass1` class isn't instantiated. End of the story.

The proper recipe to do the expected thing is providing values from JSON to class constructor. Considering that object properties (`classInstance`) can be `undefined`, class properties can't rely on default values like `constructor({ classInstance = new MyClass2 }) { ... }` and should be assigned manually:

```
export class MyClass1 {
    constructor(jsonMyClass1: MyClass1 = {}) {
        const { name, classInstance } = jsonMyClass1;
        this.name = 'name' in jsonMyClass1 ? name : "";
        this.classInstance = 'classInstance' in jsonMyClass1 ? classInstance : new MyClass2;
    }
    name: string;
    classInstance?: MyClass2;
}

let myNewClass: MyClass1 = new MyClass1({
    name: "MyClass"
});
```

When data is supplied and processed with how it will be consumed by the classes in mind (i.e. using `null` exclusively for values that are not defined), the recipe can be modified to use the powers offered by the language:

```
export class MyClass1 {
  constructor(jsonMyClass1: MyClass1 = {} as MyClass1) {
        const { name = "", classInstance = new MyClass2 } = jsonMyClass1;
        this.name = name;
        this.classInstance = classInstance;
    }
    name: string;
    classInstance: MyClass2;
}

let myNewClass: MyClass1 = new MyClass1({
    name: "MyClass",
    classInstance: null
});
```

Comment: Such a thorough answer, thanks! I just wanted to ask about this one: `const { title = "", classInstance = new MyClass2 } = jsonMyClass1;` What does this syntax do? Does it mean that first title and classInstance are assigned values, then fields in jsonMyClass1 overwrite the values that are available? But if an object is created, how do you access these variables just by typing `this.title = title;` on the next line? I'm a bit confused about the syntax, I've never seen it before. You declare const variables, that's what I do understand, but I don't understand if it's an object or separate vars?

Comment: You're welcome. It's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It creates `title` and `classInstance` temp vars, it is the cleanest way to provide default value for a var (if a prop doesn't exist on `jsonMyClass1` object or is `undefined`). The alternative is to write something like `this.classInstance = jsonMyClass1.classInstance !== undefined ? jsonMyClass1.classInstance : new Class2`. You can always check what it transpiles to at http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ , this is a great way to study TS.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, I ran into one more problem regarding to the constructors: what if classInstance is MyClass1? How do I pass make sure the data goes via constructor for the nested subclasses as well?

For example, a JSON comes through that contains:
`{ name: "MyClass1 instance at main level", classInstance: { title: "MyClass1 instance nested" } }`

How can I make sure also MyClass1 nested gets created with the constructor? I receive this whole object from json so do I have any control on how it's created in this case?

Comment: Probably it should be something like `const { title, classInstance = new MyClass1 } = jsonMyClass1` and `this.classInstance = classInstance instanceof MyClass1 ? classInstance : new MyClass1(classInstance)`. This will result in recursive class construction. If you will have problems with this approach, I would suggest to ask a new question that reflects all the relevant details. Notice that even if an object results from parsing JSON, you can pre-process an object to fit MyClass1 constructor better, if necessary. But as for classInstance, it should work as is.

Comment: Thank you again. :) I ended up writing writing constructors for all the subclasses that might exists under MyClass1 and - like you suggest - MyClass1 constructor will call them in its own constructor (MyClass1).