# Class Interface function definition - TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I've written a construct similar to the following in an Angular app (*this has been greatly simplified to demonstrate the issue*). What would prevent the `filterProperty()` function from being defined on the `item` instance inside of the `DemoSource` class?

**`export` keyword is used because each construct is defined in a separate file.**

```
export interface IProperty {
    filterProperty(): string;
}

export class Demo implements IProperty {
    displayName: string;

    filterProperty(): string {
        return this.displayName;
    }
}

export class DemoSource<TItem extends IProperty> {
    filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
    filteredData: TItem[];

    constructor(private service: IService<TItem>) {
        // A BehaviorSubject<Array<TItem>> from a service
        this.filteredData = service.data.value.slice();
    }

    connect(): Observable<TItem[]> {
        return Observable.merge(this.service.data).map(() => {
            this.filteredData = this.service.data.value.slice().filter((item: TItem) => {
                // Object doesn't support property or method 'filterProperty'
                const searchStr = item.filterProperty().toLowerCase();
                return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            });

            return filteredData;
        });
    }
}
```

When debugging at the point where `item.filter()` is called, I get the following error:

`ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'filterProperty'`

**Update**
Changed the `IProperty` contract function from `filter()` to `filterProperty()` to avoid confusion.

Here is the Error:

[image: error]

Here, you can see how the `item` instance has all of its properties properly populated, but has no `filterProperty()` function defined (it's not in **proto** either):

[image: item]

**Update**
Here are the service details:

```
@Injectable()
export class IdentityService implements IService<AppUser> {
    users = new BehaviorSubject<Array<AppUser>>([]);
    public get data(): BehaviorSubject<AppUser[]> { return this.users; }
}

export interface IService<T> {
    data: BehaviorSubject<T>;
}
```

Here is the service being populated with data from the API:
[image: service]

Here is the result of a pure API call from the browser:
[image: api]

**Certain properties have been redacted because of their data**

**Update - Transpiled JavaScript**

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Demo = (function () {
    function Demo() {}
    Object.defineProperty(Demo.prototype, "filter", {
        get: function () { return this.displayName; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Demo;
}());
exports Demo = Demo;
```

**Update**
Web App demonstrating the issue: [Typescript / Web API Interface Issue](http://typescript-interfaces.azurewebsites.net/)
GitHub Repo for the Web App: [typescript-interface-issues](https://github.com/JaimeStill/typescript-interface-issues)

Comment: What is the content of `this.service.data.value` at runtime? What is the type of `item` at runtime?

Comment: `this.service.data.value` is an `Array<Demo>` at runtime (in this given scenario), and only has the `display` property available and properly populated.

Comment: Where exactly does this.service.data.value come from? The fact that you've typed it as `Demo` Interface doesn't add `filter` method. And error message proves it. `item` object is supposed to have filter method, and it doesn't have it.

Comment: `service.data.value` corresponds to a `BehaviorSubject<Array<Demo>>` in an Angular service that is populated as the result of a Web API call.

Comment: It doesn't correspond, hence the error. item should be an instance of Demo class in order to get filter method, and it's not.

Comment: The interface is implemented on the object type specified by `TItem`. The array is simply a collection of `TItem` objects. I've changed the name of the property from `filter()` to `filterProperty()` (to avoid confusion). Inside of the `filter()` function of the array, `filterProperty()` is still not a known function for `item`.

Comment: `value` comes from JSON, isn't it? How can you be sure that it's implemented? Unless you've instantiated `Demo` with `item = new Demo`, you can be pretty sure that it's not! The question doesn't contain the the part where value is assigned, so it lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Btw, you need to address other users with @ in order to notify them.

Comment: @estus, my apologies. Please see the above update for details about the service / API.

Comment: Yes, it's plain object, so it doesn't implement Demo. Unless you're willing to traverse the array with `item = new Demo`, just don't use filterProperty method at all. In the code you've posted it isn't really necessary.

Comment: @estus, it appears the issue was that `filterProperty` wasn't provided by the C# object that was being used to serialize the JSON data, so it was never represented in the object on the client side. Not sure why you wouldn't be able to extend the model received via Web API in TypeScript. See my answer below.

Comment: JSON is for data. There surely won't be any methods (besides the fact that it was serialized on server side and filterProperty was C# and not JS method) except the ones that exist on plain Array and Object. If you need to make some JSON nodes something more than plain objects, you need to construct them manually on client side. Here's an example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43297317/3731501

Comment: @estus, I thought I was doing that by specifying a function or read-only property on the TypeScript class? If you look at the transpiled JavaScript, it definitely has the `filter` property added to the object. See update above.

Comment: Indeed, there is. But you're confusing an interface with a class instance. If you're doing `item: Demo`, it won't exist in transpiled JS, and `item` won't become `Demo` instance. It will just cheat TS and shut it up during compilation when you're calling non-existent `item.filterProperty()` method. This is exactly the case that was explained in the answer that was linked above.

Comment: Demo isn't an interface though, it's a class. `item` would be a class instance at that point. It just implements an interface contract.If it's not possible to add additional properties and functions to a TypeScript class, or we can, we just can't expect them to be existent when it is transpiled, then that feels like a glaring issue with the language itself.

Comment: It is a class but is used as an interface. `item: Demo` just cheats typing system. You need to do `item = new Demo()` to make it a real class instance. TS is a superset of JS and it acts exactly like it's expected from JS. Sorry to say that, but you have fundamental misunderstanding of how it works here, I would suggest to clarify this particular issue before digging further into Angular-specific things.

Comment: In the generic data source, all it does is constrain the generic as being required to implement IProperty. The objects from the API service are streamed into a BehaviorSubject<Array<Demo>>, and this is the data that is provided to the data source at runtime. Are you saying that because of the constraint, each object will only be treated as being an interface, even though it is cast as the generic TItem type (`item: TItem`)?

Comment: I guess, yes, that's what I mean. The only reason why types are used in code is to help TS detect inconsistencies during compilation. Types don't affect output code (except the ones that are for Angular DI). If data originates from JSON and is a structure of plain {} and [] objects, it will stay intact (as screenshots show) - even if you will use `any` anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data results from JSON response and is a structure of plain objects and arrays that only have methods that are defined on their prototypes, `Object` and `Array`.

`item` isn't really a class instance and doesn't have `filterProperty` method it's supposed to have. So it's incorrect to specify `DemoSource<IProperty>`, considering that `IProperty` is supposed to have `filterProperty`. This fools TypeScript into thinking that objects have this method, while they don't have it - they are still plain objects, specified types don't change them.

An interface that is used for generic is supposed to reflect data structure properties (not methods). For classes that are supposed to be constructed from plain objects it's a good practice to accept plain object in constructor:

```
export interface IItemData {
    displayName: string;
    id?: number;
    ...
}

export class Item implements IItemData {
    displayName: string;

    constructor({ displayName }: IItemData) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    filterProperty(): string {
        return this.displayName;
    }
}
```

Then data structure should be processed and plain items should be converted to `Item` instances:

```
export class DemoSource<TItem extends IItemData> {
    ...
    this.filteredData = this.service.data.value.slice()
    .map((item: TItem) => {
        // item doesn't have 'filterProperty'
        return new Item(item); 
    })
    .filter((item: Item) => {
        // item has 'filterProperty'
        const searchStr = item.filterProperty().toLowerCase();
        return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    ...
```

Comment: I just found out today in another comment thread that apparently the new Angular 4 HttpClient can do all of this at the time of receiving the data (more or less). You can provide a type definition to the get function, and it will type it before sending you the result. Haven't been table to test it out yet, though.

    http.get<TypeHere>('/apiurl').subscribe( ....

Comment: @diopside It will be same case as code above and will have same problems when done incorrectly. Types don't affect output code. `http.get<IItemData[]>` assumes that received data has specified data structure and will likely be the right thing to do. `http.get<Item[]>` assumes that data consists of `Item` instances and is wrong about that, because it's not.

Comment: oh right - bc hes specifying a class not an interface. I have been staring at the computer too long, I thought he was trying to define the first two exports in his file as interfaces and the third as a class.

Comment: Technically, IProperty in the OP is an interface, but it's same thing because an interface contains a method and the result is supposed to be class instance, while it's just plain object.

Comment: If I have to directly instantiate `item` to an instance of type `Item`, doesn't that defeat the purpose of using Generics / Interfaces in the first place? The intent here is to be able to use the `DemoSource` class with any item that extends the `IProperty` so that you can indirectly set the property to be filtered for any given class.

Comment: @JaimeStill No, it doesn't defeat. As it was mentioned in comments before, types exist in code solely to provide *type safety*, not to affect compiled code. TS warns you if types went wrong at compilation time and thus prevents errors at runtime (or it doesn't if it was fooled with wrong type). I would say then that intention was wrong - TS doesn't work like that and `DemoSource` doesn't need a generic. If you want to use `DemoSource` for something different than `Item`, you need to subclass it or provide another way to switch between classes at `return new ClassName(item)` line.

Comment: Nothing about the issue you are describing is mentioned in the typescript docs. See [interface: class types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types) and [generics: constraints](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)

Comment: Occam's razor should be applied here. You won't find anything in docs that would suggest that generics and types can affect code behaviour (because they cannot).

Comment: @estus, if still interested, I've created a web app / github repo that fully demonstrates the issue (See latest update on the question). [Angular code](https://github.com/JaimeStill/typescript-interface-issues/tree/master/ClientApp/app). [API Controller](https://github.com/JaimeStill/typescript-interface-issues/blob/master/Controllers/AppController.cs).

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much consistent with the code that you've already posted. It's still the same, generics in `CoreDataSource` won't help you to get desired effect and aren't really useful there, hardcoding `CoreDataSource` to `Data` would work. Create `Data` instances with `new`, as shown in the answer (`return new Item(item)`).

Comment: @estus, instead of using `new Data()` in the `CoreDataSource`, I iterated through the JSON objects on the Angular service in a `map()` function, then returned a new array of instantiated `Data` objects. I am making an update to the sample web app I put together, because I think a larger discussion should be made towards actually making TypeScript function the way you might think it should if you come from an OOP background (like I do).

Comment: I'd also like to thank you for your patience through this whole issue. You've been an awesome help.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, this will probably work, too. If you have some blank spots in TS, I would suggest to clarify them individually, not as a part of development process of a bigger app, this is far more efficient (and allows to ask smaller questions and receive answers faster, too). Just keep in mind that the only new things in TS are OOP visibility, types (i.e. type error detection during compilation, no more, no less) and Enum. The rest is pure JS (ES2017), so the issues you may encounter may be specific to JS in the first place - and yes, it may differ a lot from other OO languages.

Comment: @estus, the [sample app](http://typescript-interfaces.azurewebsites.net/) that I created has been updated to reflect the thought process that went into creating everything the way I did, and the lessons learned. I still don't really like the truth of it, but it's what I have to work with I suppose.

Comment: I see. Yes, it looks like you're heading in the right direction. The important part is that TS won't make your code shorter or leaner than its JS counterpart - in fact, it's always more verbose, and sometimes you can't use nice JS hacks because they don't play well with strict typing. But on the large scale it often pays off because random typos and human errors are caught by the compiler (plus rock solid autocomplete in IDE and self-documented code).

Comment: simplified the mapping with `return res.json().map(array => { return array.map(data => return { Object.assign(new Data(), data); });`

Comment: Notice that `Object.assign(new Data(), data)` is a dangerous move. If `data` contains props that don't have to be there, they will be assigned any way. I.e. `{ filterProperty: null }` will shadow `Data`'s `filterProperty` method. Usually it's a good thing to pick known props and assign then in constructor (like is shown in `Item` class).

Comment: I write all of the APIs too, so I have control over the objects I'm receiving from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As I think `filter` is reserved keyword. So that angular trying to implement `filter` function on type `Object`. `filter` can be used only for `Array` . try using different name for the function.

If this is not the case. Maybe the service data item should come as `Object` instead of `TTem` instance.We can get the class methods only on its instances. Can you try creating new instance as follows

```
this.filteredData = this.service.data.value.slice().filter(
(item: TItem) => {
            // Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'
            let instance: TItem = new TItem();
            Object.assign(instance, item);
            const searchStr = instance.filter().toLowerCase();
            return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !==-1;
        });
```

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on the below answer, changing the function name had no effect.

Comment: I have modified the answer. Try to check is this can work..!!

Comment: Getting: `ERROR TypeError: Object.assign: argument is not an Object`

Comment: `Object.assign()` is a buit in function . How i may not worked !!. Check similar builtin fuctions are working properly for you i.e `Object.keys()`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working the way I had originally wanted it to with the below setup. The key was, apparently, adding a `filter` property to the C# object that was being used to serialize data to JSON via Web API. Not sure why this would be required, as TypeScript should be able to extend the model received from Web API with additional functionality.

*Example simplified to demonstrate the problem set*

**DemoModel.cs**

```
// C# Class JSON is serialized from via Web API
public class DemoModel
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string filter
    {
        get { return displayName; }
    }
}
```

**iproperty.interface.ts**

```
export interface IProperty {
    filter: string;
}
```

**demo.model.ts**

```
import { IProperty } from '../interfaces/iproperty.interface';

export class Demo implements IProperty {
    displayName: string;
    get filter(): string { return this.displayName; }
}
```

**core.datasource.ts**

```
export class CoreDataSource<TItem extends IProperty> {
    filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
    filteredData: TItem[];
    get filter(): string { return this.filterChange.value; }
    set filter(filter: string) { this.filterChange.next(filter); }

    constructor(private service: IService<TItem>) {
        super();
        this.filteredData = service.data.value.slice();
    }

    connect(): Observable<TItem[]> {
        const displayDataChanges = [
            this.service.data,
            this.filterChange
        ];

        return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
            this.filteredData = this.service.data.value.slice().filter((item: TItem) => {
                const searchStr = item.filter.toLowerCase();
                return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            });

            return filteredData;
        });
    }
}
```