# Promise not returning a valid class instance

Tags: angular, typescript

I've just started learning Typescript and I'm already lost in something that sounds really strange for a C# developer.

**Summary:** `Promise<WsIdSessionResponse>` returns a variable that has same fields of `WsIdSessionResponse` class but it's not a valid `WsIdSessionResponse` instance.

**Long story**
I have a service like this (I've omitted something useless for the problem) consuming a JSON webservice not written by me:

```
export class WsIdSessionService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    doLoginAsync(user: string, pwd: string): Promise<WsIdSessionResponse> {
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('username', user);
        params = params.append('password', pwd);
        return this.http.get<WsIdSessionResponse>(this.apiUrl, {params: params})
            .toPromise());
    };
```

**WsIdSessionResponse** class is like this

```
export class WsIdSessionResponse {
    public status: number;
    public username: string;

    public isOk(): boolean {
        return this.status == 1;
    }
}
```

Problem comes when I retrieve data from `WsIdSessionService`:

```
var idSvc = this.wsIdSession.doLoginAsync(user, pwd);
var t = idSvc.then(info => {
    if (t.isOk()) {
      // Do something here
    }
}
```

When I execute `t.isOk()` I get an error telling me that `isOk()` is not a function!
What?!? Not a function? Yes it is, I have that function in my class!

After wasting a huge amount of time, I finally thought about trying this code

```
var idSvc = this.wsIdSession.doLoginAsync(user, pwd);
var t = idSvc.then(info => {
    console.warn(`info is valid: ${info instanceof WsIdSessionResponse}`);
}
```

Here I get a `false` as result: so returned variable has same fields of the class I need but it's not a real instance of the class and that's the reason `isOk()` function is not valid!
But how is this possible? I mean, `http.get<WsIdSessionResponse>` should return a valid instance of the `WsIdSessionResponse` or eventually an error... am I wrong?

Just to provide complete infos: `http.get<WsIdSessionResponse>` gets data from a url returning a plain JSON string.

Is this the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like the user had exactly same problem with C# background. TS is just JS with type errors on compilation. It doesn't do magic transforms on objects that wouldn't be expected from JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<WsIdSessionResponse>` doesn't make the object an instance of `WsIdSessionResponse`. It cheats typing system to think that it is an instance and suppresses type errors. TypeScript is JavaScript with type safety, and it is just JavaScript when it's compiled.

Unless an instance of `WsIdSessionResponse` is created explicitly with `new`, the object will stay `Object`, with no `isOk` method.

The way it's supposed to work is:

```
interface IWsIdSessionResponse {
    status: number;
    username: string;
}

class WsIdSessionResponse implements IWsIdSessionResponse {
    public status: number;
    public username: string;

    public isOk(): boolean {
        return this.status == 1;
    }
}

...

doLoginAsync(user: string, pwd: string): Promise<WsIdSessionResponse> {
        ...
        return this.http.get<IWsIdSessionResponse>(this.apiUrl, {params: params})
            .map(plainResponseObj => Object.assign(new WsIdSessionResponse, plainResponseObj))
            .toPromise());
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already solved by manually creating an instance, but in a less elegant and fast way. You're right about JS, I just have to learn the differences with C# and I'm sure I'm going to have a lot of headaches.

Comment: When I use `.map(resp=>` I get an error stating that `Property map doesn't exist on type 'Observable<IWsIdSessionResponse>'`.
Even removing the type and using plain `http.get` I still get the same error for type `Observable<Object>`

Comment: You're welcome. Object.assign is a bit of a hack over existing class. The proper pattern here would be is to have self-filling class constructor (see `Item` here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45847569/3731501 ). `doesn't exist on type 'Observable` is regular problem with observables in Angular 4. Use `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`, etc for each operator you're using.

Comment: I understand that I have a long way to go without too much time unfortunately, but I think this could be the future and I'd better learn this! Thanks so much for your support!