# HttpClient type safety seems to ignore interface

Tags: angular, typescript

## TL;DR:

1. An angular interface was defined and bound to `HttpClient.get()` responses.
2. Responses were mapped to a seemingly generic `object` type.
3. Attributes that weren't defined on the interface like `id` and `title` were accessible on the response, as well as from .html called (eg. `<p>Title is:
   {{message?.title}}</p>`.
4. If an interface is a contract, shouldn't it be preventing some of this?

---

New to Angular 4 from a Java background and stumbling on `HttpClient` type safety.  As [this guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) points out, one can pass an interface to `http.get<>` to typecheck an HTTP response.

Consider a basic interface with a single `foo` field:

```
export interface FooInterface{
   foo: string;
}
```

Following the aforementioned guide, this interface can easily be bound to a response:

```
export class RestComponent {

   message: FooInterface;

    http.get<FooInterface>('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
        this.message = data;
        console.log(this.message);
        console.log(typeof(this.message));
        console.log(this.message.foo);
    });
```

At this point, **I hit a random API which does not have a `foo` field**.  The actual API has two fields: *id* and *title*.  To my surprise, when I hit this API, the data object was still created:

[image]

Data is a generic object with fields `id` and `title`.  A call to `data.foo` return `undefined`.

Furthermore, while the interface prevents me from accessing these *id* and *title* fields directly, they are still available through calls like `data['id']`.  They can also be referenced in the HTML.

```
<h1>
  id: {{message.id}}
  <br>
  title: {{message?.title}}
</h1>
```

And this gets rendered!  In fact, the only thing the interface seems to do is prevent me from doing something like:

```
`this.message.title`
```

That's cool I guess... but if these fields can be accessed via `this.message['title']` or reference in html files, then what's the point of the interface?

[image]

Comment: Just providing a generic type does **not** mean Angular does any casting or validation. *"Typechecking"* is perhaps not the clearest way for the docs to refer to this. It's just a hint for your benefit, so you can document the shape you're expecting to receive and get help from the compiler when subsequently interacting with it. If you need some conversion, you will have to write that yourself.

Comment: That's where I felt like this was going, but thought an interface was a contract, not a hint.  Do you recommend any utilities/shortcuts for doing these conversions?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that idea, note that TS's typing is *only* at compile time. We just wrote our own mapping methods as needed; if you want a library, I'd suggest heading to NPM.

Comment: I guess I assumed too much correspondence with java, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844055/class-interface-function-definition-typeerror-object-doesnt-support-property

Comment: Devs with C# or Java background often have problems with TS types, for a reason. Also, `data['id']` is a legit technique to skip type checks when needed, and types in template can't be checked for obvious reason with JIT compiler, because it's a string that is ignored by TS - but they surely will be checked with AOT.

Answer (score 0):

When comming from a Java background, the generic problem with TypeScript typing is that types are not enforced. Whenever you do a cast in TypeScript, no runtime exception is thrown if the object is not of that class. The exception is thrown later when accessing the missing fields of that object.

What you want to do is not compile time type checking (as TypeScript does) but you want to enforce a specific type of the response.

You can do this by checking the response manually:

```js
    http.get<FooInterface>('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
        if (typeof data !== 'object')
          throw new Error('Expected an object')
        if (typeof data.foo !== 'string')
          throw new Error('Expected a string property')
        this.message = data;
    });
```

If you want to automate this, have a look at JSON Schema validation. You need to define a JSON schema in addition to your TypeScript class. There is [a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-typescript) that will help you keep them in sync. There are also libraries that can automatically generate them from e.g. Spring REST endpoints, so you can keep them in sync with your backend services.