# Angular 2/4 - Typed http response

Tags: json, angular, http, typescript

I wrote an Angular 4 http get request to get data from my API. I cast the result to the interface : IPerson[]. However if some attribute from the http request are not the same type or not the same name, it's fine for him no error.

Why doesn't it raise an error ? That means we can't type checking on http request ?

Here is the code for the interface IPerson.ts :

```
export interface IPerson {
  AAA: number;
  BBB: string;
  CCC: number;
  DDD: string;
  FFF: number;
  EEE: number;
}
```

And for the Angular service :

```
getFonction(): Observable<IPerson[]> {
    return this._http
      .get<IPerson[]>('../../../assets/example.json')
      .timeout(10000)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

If in the json.exemple I have :

```
[{
   -> ABC: boolean; <-
      BBB: string;
      CCC: number;
      DDD: string;
      FFF: number;
      EEE: number;
},
{
   -> ABC: boolean; <-
      BBB: string;
      CCC: number;
      DDD: string;
      FFF: number;
      EEE: number;
}]
```

And I save the data from the http call request in a variable called "persons: Person[]" and I console log it I still have (an no error) :

```
[{
   -> ABC: boolean; <-
      BBB: string;
      CCC: number;
      DDD: string;
      FFF: number;
      EEE: number;
},
{
   -> ABC: boolean; <-
      BBB: string;
      CCC: number;
      DDD: string;
      FFF: number;
      EEE: number;
}]
```

Comment: *"I cast the result to the interface"* - no, that is **not** what is happening. TypeScript is purely a compile-time tool, when the request is made those types are no longer in the codebase. The type on the request method should be *what you're actually receiving*, so that the compiler and your IDE can tell you if your code makes sense given that input; if you need to validate or convert that, you need to *write that functionality explicitly*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46839214/3001761

Comment: Thank you very much for that enlightenment !