# How do you parse json res data to a model in http observable?

Tags: angular, http, model, observable, angular6

I would like to know how you can parse a json object into a model and use that model inside an array. I tried the following, but it didn't work for me after receiving data in the Observable:

```
getExampleData() : Observable<MyModel[]> {
  return this.http.get<MyModel[]>( this.exampleGetURL ).pipe(
    map((res:Response) => res),
    catchError( this.handleError )
  );
}
```

And here, I tried to log res data that should have been parsed into MyModel[], but it still is a json object instead.

```
this.myService.getExampleData().subscribe( (res:MyModel[]) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

This is the model:

```
export class MyModel {
  public name   :string;
  public price  :number;

  constructor( name:string, price:number ) {
    this.name   = name;
    this.price  = price;
  }
  public printDetails() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

What can I do about this situation?

update:

I know that this isn't the right way, because we should keep our code clean and neatly as possible, but I know that this does work:

```
getExampleData() : Observable<MyModel[]> {
    return <Observable<MyModel[]>>this.http.get( this.exampleGetURL ).pipe(
      map(res => {
        let myModels:MyModel[] = [];
        for( let el of <MyModel[]>res )
          myModels.push( new MyModel(el.name, el.price) );
        return myModels;
      }),
      catchError( this.handleError )
    );
  }
```

Is there a way to clean this mess?

Comment: Are you using HttpClient or HTTP?

Comment: I am using HttpClient.

Comment: I just updated my post. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: check first your res and see if it contains other properties than the result, if your res = { succeeded: "treu", data: [your response here]} you have to access it map((res:Response) => res.data

Comment: @FatehMohamed

I tried exactly what you said, but I get undefined as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model `MyModel` is a class. The `HttpClient` parses the body to plain objects (which normally could be defined by an `interface`), not class instances. ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21107))

But even changing your model to an interface will not solve your issue. Angular is not doing any casting. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839214/httpclient-type-safety-seems-to-ignore-interface) for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HttpClient, here is another way of doing it:

```
getExampleData() : Observable<MyModel[]> {
  return this.http.get( this.exampleGetURL ).pipe(
    map((res:MyModel[]) => res),
    catchError( this.handleError )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to simply cast your observable with the wanted type:

```
getExampleData() : Observable<MyModel[]> {
  return <Observable<MyModel[]>> this.http.get( this.exampleGetURL ).pipe(
    catchError( this.handleError )
  );
}
```

Also, I recommend you use an http interceptor to handle your errors so that you wont have to catch them in every service.

Comment: Didn't change the effects of it. I still get to see the same result.

Thank you for the interceptor advice.

Comment: I just saw you screenshot, and you're already getting MyModel objects xD

Comment: No, I wrote the following to test if I could convert it manually (that is why you see the MyModel array items at the end):


let cms = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      let cm = new MyModel(res[0].name, res[0].price);
      cms.push(cm);
    }

    console.log(cms);
    cms[0].printDetails();

It should be clear.