# TypeScript: class property optional but not undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop

Is there any way that you can have a property on a `Class` that is optional, but won't be undefined?

Note in the example below, the `Class` constructor takes a type of itself (that's intentional)

```js
class Test {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz?: string;

  constructor(test: Test) {
    this.foo = test.foo;
    this.bar = test.bar
    this.baz = test.baz || "Default";
  }
}

const first = new Test({foo: 1, bar: "Bob"});

const str = "Some Default String about Bob";

str.replace(first.baz, "New Value");
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | RegExp'.(
```

I know I can use the `!` operator, but would prefer not to

```js
str.replace(first.baz!, "New Value");
```

Seems maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295756/possible-to-have-typescript-class-optional-properties-fall-back-to-default-value) addresses it the answer — "class properties can't rely on default values"

Comment: Optional means undefined

Comment: Construct a different type to take in your constructor

Comment: @DanielA.White It is not the same. There can be a huge difference between a property not being there at all and a property existing with value equal to `undefined`. (Which is why the flag [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) exists.)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you don't want the *class property* to be optional you want the *constructor parameter* to be optional. Which is easy enough to do:

```js
interface TestParams {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz?: string; // optional
}

class Test {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz: string; // NOTE: not optional!

  constructor ({
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
  }: TestParams) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = baz ?? "Default";
  }
}
```

Note that I used the nullish coalescing operator rather than logical "or" so that if `baz` is undefined we'll assign the default but if it's an empty sting it won't be overwritten. If you are really concerned about the duplication, and you don't mind having your constructor take positional parameters rather than an object you can condense it back down quite a bit:

```js
class Test2 {
  constructor (
    public foo: number,
    public bar: string,
    public baz = "Default",
  ) {}
}
```

The behavior isn't *quite* the same regarding the optional param, but it's pretty close.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gApynAWw2QG8BYAKGWRgHtaAuZEAVwICNoBuS69vJliigA5jyrJ+ALwD8gsMJBjKAX0qUEAGzgZi6LKV416TVh25H+UeYuUTpN0eKMJaIISwRhaUZAApyCWo6WgAaIz48cKDJOClo6hUmfRw8QgwASkMYsAALYAwAOhDkAF5jWnFqajyCwqsy2Kgq6tqi6UaOmRlkACIAEQh4Fk0wXpa1CkmNbV00TDAAJmzqV3cFT29fPwjkAAcWdk1gBArTNk4oBOqDo5OmxyVr6lvj047ygaG4EbHrrJIk0mQA)

Comment: "you don't want the class property to be optional you want the constructor parameter to be optional." — yes, that reframes the question much better! Positional parameters aren't an option, but now I'm on a better path

Comment: Regarding duplication, one can use utility types to [derive the params from the class type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgawgeTMAlgewHZwDYA8AKgDRQDSUEAHsBNgCYDOUSImAZlEQHxQC8AWABQUKMgC26YMTLk+AMigAFOACcM+AsvQBjBLIo8eAbhEjdeOExZEITYFADeIsR0yYAhAC4o2AK4SAEYQamaiUEHqPlAOaujYAObhYlEAXr5xCYkCUABEACIQHHD+eMB54a5Qujhx-rrAmGpQABSYvnYOqmpwEkwAlM7VYsAAFuhMAHTumLmYMx4pYlDjk1NRLfxQC5vLoxPT6fMbcGlQAPwX+UUlZRXLAL4iz8IioJDc9sA9fSzb8CQqAwOC0XWAZAA5OlIaZzMJatgmJg8BApnhMIlWtgIAB3L4OVouCKzXwARhI1U2vkhnkhlOEjwGA3CQA).